# Replace text with sed

Tags: bash, sed, solaris, tr

A program creates HTML files from a database. There are headings and stuff in between the headings.

There are not a set amount of headings. 
After each heading the program places the text:

```
$WHITE*("5")$ 

$WHITE*("20")$ 
$HRULE$
```

I need every occurrence of these 4 lines to be replaced with:

```
$WHITE*("20")$ 
$HRULE$ 
$WHITE*("10")$
```

I am not fussed what program is used :)

I have tried:

```
sed 's:\$WHITE\*(\"5\")\$\n\n\$WHITE\*(\"20\")\$\n\$HRULE\$:\$WHITE\*(\"20\")\$\
\$HRULE$\
\$WHITE*("10")$:g'
```

and various other permutations

Comment: What is the relationship between the input and the output? E.g. how did the first line go from `$WHITE*("5")$` to `$WHITE*("20")$`, etc?

Comment: You might fare better with GNU userland tools. Chances are you have them but you  need to explicitely call `gsed` (`ggrep`, `gfind` etc.) to get the GNU versions. The GNU versions are invariably more feature rich and enjoy greater popularity on the web

Comment: By the way, show us what you tried. It doesn't matter that it didn't work, but 'it didn't work' doesn't give us much of a clue as to what you want/what we don't need to try first. -1 until you add info

Comment: The input is produced by a tool which I cannot change, the particular lines need to be changed in order for it to be parsed correctly by another program which I cannot change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE #2

From the sed faq, section [4.23.3](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.23.3)

> If you need to match a static block of text (which may occur any number of times throughout a file), where the contents of the block are known in advance, then this script is easy to use

UPDATE #1

Python?

```
$ cat input
first line
second line
3rd line
$WHITE*("5")$

$WHITE*("20")$
$HRULE$
some more lines
yet another
$WHITE*("5")$

$WHITE*("20")$
$HRULE$
THE END
```

the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

## Use these 3 lines for python version < 2.5
#fd=open('input')
#text=fd.read()
#fd.close()

## Use these 2 lines for python version >= 2.5
with open('input') as fd:
    text=fd.read()

old="""$WHITE*("5")$

$WHITE*("20")$
$HRULE$
"""

new="""$WHITE*("20")$
$HRULE$
$WHITE*("10")$
"""

print text.replace(old,new)
```

output:

```
first line
second line
3rd line
$WHITE*("20")$
$HRULE$
$WHITE*("10")$
some more lines
yet another
$WHITE*("20")$
$HRULE$
$WHITE*("10")$
THE END
```

Comment: I have modified the description, please check to see if you understand what I need better, thanks

Comment: well, perhaps a bit better :-) your first description was very vague

Comment: Thanks, I have never used python though, what do i save the scripts as and how do I run it? I am using bash on solaris 5.10

Comment: call it `filter.py`, make it executable using `chmod 755 filter.py`, change line 3 to reflect the actual filename (I used `input` in my example), execute it using `./filter.py` that is provided you have python installed :-). Change the shebang (the first line to contain the path to where python is installed, however the env trick should work out-of-the-box if python is in your path. I can post a perl-solution if you're more comfortable using that instead.

Comment: I get errors:

  File "./filter.py", line 4
    with open('test.txt') as fd:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you might be on a old version of python, the `with` keyword was added in 2.5. I'll update code above that doesn't use `with`

Comment: Ok thanks this works now, well I get it printed to the terminal, how do I modify it so the text is actually replaced in the file? Thanks for your help, I also tried the sed faq but even that doesn't work probably due to an old version of sed.

Comment: simplest way is to use a redirection and a move i.e. `./filter.py > tmp && mv tmp test.txt`

Comment: I got it sorted, just did:

text = text.replace(pattern,replace)

fd=open(sys.argv[1],"w")
fd.writelines(text)
fd.close()

Thanks for introducing me to python :)

Comment: a day with another python convert isn't completely wasted! glad you liked python, its a truly amazing language. Good luck and keep your posts coming

Answer (score 1):

If that'S your input file, and this is the spec, you can do:

```
sed -n '3,$p;$a$WHITE*("10")$' INPUTFILE
```

But I assume that's not the case, so you might want to rephrase your question and/or giving some more detailes.

More specific solution with sed:

```
 sed '/^\$WHITE\*("5")\$$/,/^$/d;/\$HRULE\$/ a$WHITE*("10")$' INPUTFILE
```

(Searches for the `$WHITE*("5")$` line and deletes it till (including!) the next empty line. Then searches for the next `$HRULE$` line and appends an  `$WHITE*("10")$` line.

`awk` solution:

```
 awk '/\$WHITE\*\("5"\)\$/ { getline ; next } 
      /\$WHITE\*\("20"\)\$/ { print ; 
                              getline ; 
                              if ($0 ~ /\$HRULE\$/) { print ; 
                                                      print "$WHITE*(\"10\")$" ;
                                                    }
                              else { print }
                            }
      1 ' INPUTFILE
```

This reads the file and prints every line - that's why the `1` is there, except if it finds the `$WHITE*("5")` pattern it drops it, reads the next line and drops that too. if it finds the `$WHITE*("20")` prints it. Reads the next line and if its `$HRULE$` then prints that and the appended `$WHITE*("10")` line. Else just prints the line.

HTH

Comment: I just want to exactly replace the top text with the bottom text

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
 sed -e '${p;};/$WHITE\*("5")\$/,/$HRULE\$/{H;/$HRULE\$/{g;s/$HRULE\$//;s/20/10/;s/5/20/;s/\n/&$HRULE$/2p;s/.*//p;x;d;};d;};' white.txt
```

Crude, but it should work.

Comment: @AydinHassan: What version of sed?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/^\$WHITE\*(\"5\")\$/{N;N;N;s/.*\n\n\(\(\$WHITE\*(\"\)20\(\")\$\s*\)\n\$HRULE\$\s*$\)/\1\n\210\3/}' file
```

Explanation:

Match on first string `$WHITE*("5")$`, read the next 3 lines and match on remainder. Use grouping and back references to formulate output lines.

Comment: doesn't work: echo -e '$WHITE*("10")$\n\n$WHITE*("20")$\n$HRULE$' | sed '/^\$WHITE\*(\"5\")\$/{N;N;N;s/.*\n\n\(\(\$WHITE\*(\"\)20\(\")\$\s*\)\n\$HRULE\$\s*$\)/\1\n\210\3/}'
sed: Extra text at end of command: /^\$WHITE\*(\"5\")\$/{N;N;N;s/.*\n\n\(\(\$WHITE\*(\"\)20\(\")\$\s*\)\n\$HRULE\$\s*$\)/\1\n\210\3/}

Comment: @AydinHassan you said in the question it must match `$WHITE*("5")$ 

$WHITE*("20")$ 
$HRULE$ ` not `$WHITE*("10")$.....`